# websocket.exception.ConnectionClosedError: code 4000 (privat use) - Python Discord Bot

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, bots, discord.py, raspberry-pi4

i am currently learning python und started with a discord bot. the bot is running on raspberry pi behind my privat router. the code contains some while loops, which starts when "on_ready" is triggerd. they should never stop, so far the plan. here an example:

```
# Auto cleanup
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if self.currently_active == False:
            self.currently_active = True
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            while True:
                dome some stuff
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Now, the problem i have is, that the loops stopping after some time. it looks like, the loop which stops executing, is completly random. i think i figureds out, that they stop at night and i catched the error (titel says it). i think the problem is the 24hours dsl reconnect, which my router does every night in combination with on_ready, but i am not sure.
can someone explain me the error and maybe havean idea for a workaround?

PS: i have no experience whith exception/error handling yet.

Comment: Host on a hosting site, for example, Heroku, https://dashboard.heroku.com

Comment: thx for your response. i dont want to do that. no reason, just a persoanl decision. :)

Answer (score 0):

So...i guess i figured it out somehow.
instead of creating a infinte loop, i used this:
[discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/)

i just followed the example and it seems to work fine.